# $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is integrally closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

> I have been thinking about how to prove that the integral domain $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is integrally closed and I am writing this post to ask for proof verification.

Attempt.

Let $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. Then $Q(R)=\frac{R}{\{nonzero\:elements\: of\:R\}}$. But {nonzero elements of $R$} is the complement of $(x^2+y^2-1)$ which is the prime ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. So letting $p=(x^2+y^2-1)$, $Q(R)=(\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1))_p=R_p.$ Let $\overline{R}$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $Q(R)$. Then since $(\overline{R})_p$ is the integral closure of $R_p(=Q(R))$ in $Q(R)_p(=Q(R))$, $\overline{R}_p=R_p$. And for all other primes $p'$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, $p'^c\cap p\neq\emptyset$. So $R_{p'}=0={\overline{R}}_{p'}$, which concludes $R=\overline{R}$.

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630253/showing-fx-y-ax2by2-1-is-a-dedekind-domain), and Vicenzo's answer.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408078/) provides an alternative approach.

Comment: TBH I don't understand a word from what you are doing here, starting with the description of Q(R).

Comment: @user26857 by $Q(R)$, I mean the field of fractions of an integral domain.

Comment: I have no doubt about it!

Comment: Reopened. Reason: the OP has asked for a proof verification.

Comment: $Q(R)=R_p$ is wrong.