# How can I find the normalization of a singular hyperelliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

> Given a hyperelliptic plane curve
>   $$
> X = \text{Spec}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{y^2 - x(x-1)(x-2)^4} \right)
> $$
>   how can I find its normalization?

I know I am suppose to compute the integral closure of the morphism
$$
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{y^2 - x(x-1)(x-2)^4} \to \text{Frac}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{y^2 - x(x-1)(x-2)^4} \right)
$$
and this will give me the algebra of the normalized curve.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/681926/121097

Comment: @user26857 the target is to get a Dedekind domain whose fraction field is the function field of the curve ?