# Show that this domain is integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

The following is stated on the Wikipedia entry for integrally closed domains as an example:

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic not $2$ and $S=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ a polynomial ring over it. If $f$ is a square-free nonconstant polynomial, then $A=S[y]/(y^2-f)$ is an integrally closed domain.

If I am correct, then $A$ is just $S$ adjointed $\sqrt f $. But I still don't see how one can prove that $A$ is integrally closed.

Comment: Try to adapt [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/681926/121097).

Comment: $S$ can be any UFD with $2$ invertible in it.